SEPIC DC-DC converter
I want to do the layout for a SEPIC DC/DC converter as follows:

In the datasheet of the driver LM3488, they have recommendation for layout, which means the traces should be as short as possible for specific traces, as it is shown in the following picture. I'm trying to understand how can I correlated C1, C2, L, Q, D to the left schematic component? For example where is C1 (in the right image) in the left schematic and also the other components?
Regards

Keep in mind that the LM3488 chip handles multiple topologies, and that the layout pattern that you are following is for boost and incomplete for SEPIC. Your job is to find and minimize all significant current loops. Also, "the traces should be as short as possible" means inductively, resistively, etc, and not necessarily just simple distance.

Does this help you understand: -

